# Storing ListBox items in separate variables

Tags: c#

There could be up to four items in my `ListBox` control. I want to assign the text displayed to string variables but I am running into problems with the index being out of range as soon as it gets to `string Two`. I know why this is happening (only one item in the listbox...) but I can't seem to get my head around how to do it.

I could possibly construct some kind of if statement to deal with this but I think there may be a more efficient method of doing it, rather than checking if it's less than 2 items, more than 1, etc.

Simple version of my code:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count < 4) {
        listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
    } else {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Too many");
    }

    string One = listBox1.Items[0].ToString();
    string Two = listBox1.Items[1].ToString();
    string Three = listBox1.Items[2].ToString();
    string Four = listBox1.Items[3].ToString();
}
```

Note that I **cannot** use an array for this, as I need to access the variables in another application which does not have the ability to iterate through an array or access its indexes.

Comment: is the other application using the common language runtime too?

Comment: You might need separate methods for the adding of the items (`if-else` part), and for getting the items (`One, Two..` part)

Comment: Yes the other application is .NET based. Essentially what will happen is that all variables declared in a wizard (aka, my form, where this code lives) get put into a datatable, which is then referenced using merge codes in Microsoft Word, which doesn't have the ability to deal with arrays, only the columns and one row in a datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a temporary array to handle the copying for you:

```
if (listBox1.Items.Count < 4) {
    listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
} else {
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Too many");
}

string[] ListItemsArray= new string[4];
listBox1.Items.CopyTo(ListItemsArray, 0);

//Then you can leave this here:
string One   = ListItemsArray[0] ?? "";
string Two   = ListItemsArray[1] ?? "";
string Three = ListItemsArray[2] ?? "";
string Four  = ListItemsArray[3] ?? "";
```

The `listBox1.Items.CopyTo()` method is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.copyto).

The `??` operator is used if you don't want any value to be null

Comment: All good answers but I like this one the best as it seems to make the most sense (to me). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If its really just up to 4 items, then manually knock it out?

```
string One = "";
string Two = "";
string Three = "";
string Four = "";

if (listBox1.Items.Count >= 1)
{
    One = listBox1.Items[0];
}
if (listBox1.Items.Count >= 2)
{
    Two = listBox1.Items[1];
}
if (listBox1.Items.Count >= 3)
{
    Three = listBox1.Items[2];
}
if (listBox1.Items.Count >= 4)
{
    Four = listBox1.Items[3];
}
```

Its not elegant, but the job is done.

Comment: That's what i was going to do but i just wondered if there was a more efficient and future proof way, incase it ever increases to say, 10 items.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *for* loop over the *listBox.Items* so you never try to access indices that are out of range.

You could first create an array of strings like so:

```
string[] names = new string[] { "", "", "", "" };
```

Then you could use a for loop over the items of the listbox and set the strings of the array of strings you just created to be equal to whatever is in the listBox[index].ToString() like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            names[i] = listBox.Items[i].ToString();
        }
```

Finally, you set your original variables with the :

```
string one = names[0];
string two = names[1];
string three = names[2];
string four = names[3];
```

If any of the strings above is an empty string, it means you didn't have any item on that position in the listbox or the item you had in the listbox implements ToString() to return an empty string.

Not sure if I understood your problem, but I'd do something like that.